# PDF Download in HREF of a-element results in empty PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, data-uri

I use a-element as download-button for files I have had to query with AJAX before as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676649/javascript-programmatically-trigger-file-download-in-firefox), [here](http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2016/05/angularjs-download-files-by-sending.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818785/how-to-download-a-file-programmatically-using-js-internet-explorer). I put to put the file-data as Data-URI into a a-element to create a download-button. Unfortunately I can not just point to the file but have to do it like that. With most download-formats HTML, CSV it works like this:

```
var mimeType = "text/html"; // example. works also with others.
var BOM = '\ufeff';
var url = "data:"+ mimeType +";charset=UTF-8," + BOM + encodeURIComponent(response.data);
var linkElem = document.querySelector("#hiddenDownloadLink");
var link = angular.element(linkElem);
link.prop("href", url);
link.prop("download", 'myFile.' + extension);
linkElem.click();
```

Okay. That works. But not for PDF.

I create a PDF in my backend (java, with openhtmltopdf but it doesn't matter I guess, since the PDF is definitely correct):

```
httpOutputMessage.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/pdf");
httpOutputMessage.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"myFile.pdf\"");
makePdf(httpOutputMessage.getBody());
```

If I query the backend directly, or even if I log the output into a file, everything is fine. But when I use my download-controller as described above, **I get a PDF with the right number of pages but completely empty!** I think there must be an encoding issue. I tried with and without BOM, also with or without encodeURIComponent.

I also tried to use the base64-decoding as. Because window.atob(response.data) fails because of line breaks and others, I tried [this](http://this) conversion. The result is an broken PDF. Results in broken PDFs. I am not sure if that makes any sense.

My PDF-data starts like this, so it's not compressed or encoded anyhow:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Version /1.7
/Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
```

I also tried to convert the bytestream to blob and generate a link as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805330/opening-pdf-string-in-new-window-with-javascript) or[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150333/html5-javascript-dataurl-to-blob-blob-to-dataurl), but that creates broken PDFs.

Any Ideas, why I get empty PDFs or what might go wrong here and how can I repait the download-link?

--
Edit 1

I also get valid, but blank PDF when I try

```
var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.prop("href", url);
```

When I pipe response.data through this function, I get a broken PDF.

```
var utf8_to_b64 = function(str) {
  var unescape = window.unescape || window.decodeURI;
  str = encodeURIComponent(str);
  str = unescape(str);
  str = window.btoa(str);

  return str;
};
```

Comment: "since the PDF is definitely correct" - and how do you know this?

Comment: As I wrote - I tested to call the backend directly with postman, and I wrote a pdf-file from backend on the servers harddrive, and in both cases it got a correct pdf with contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I could fully reproduce your situation. I loaded and output a 4 page PDF file through an AJAX request from backend, and with your code example got a 4 page blank PDF.

Here's what I did after (and got the right PDF to download):

I base64 encoded the output from the backend. In my case I was using PHP so it was something like this:

```
$pdf = file_get_contents('test.pdf');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo base64_encode($pdf);
```

Then in the frontend I changed only this line:

```
var url = "data:"+ mimeType +";charset=UTF-8," + BOM + encodeURIComponent(response.data);
```

to this:

```
var url = "data:"+ mimeType +";base64," + encodeURIComponent(response.data);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped because I realized that I had to do the BASE64 by myself. Then I used your url and it worked. Except that now you can not access backend directly, but that's not necessary.